# Округлить число к заданному интервалу

Tags: javascript, jquery, числа

Есть какое-то число от 1 до 60.
Нужно проверять его и округлять до числа из отрезка, то есть если мы получили число от 1 до 14, то округляем до 15. Если число от 16 до 29, то округляем до 30, если число от 31 до 44, то до 45 и если от 46 до 59, то число равно 00

Числа до которых округлять - это отрезки до 15, 30, 45, 00.

Написала код с кучей `if` и понимаю, что такого быть не должно.

Как его правильно сделать ?

Вот мой ужасный пример http://jsfiddle.net/w048qu7n/ . Я брала и округляла по остатку от деления.

Comment: Небольшое замечание, не относящееся к округлению. Но тем не менее, независимо от выбранного ответа, рекомендую добавить проверку на недопустимые значения `number > 0 && number <= 60`, т.к. на вход всегда может попасть любое число (-1, 0, 65 100500).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте формулу:

```
((Math.floor((n - 1) / 15) + 1) * 15) % 60
```

где `n` - это число из какого-то интервала.

Comment: не могу сообразить зачем мы отнимаем 1?

Comment: @ennet, потому, что если мы не отнимем 1 от 15 например, то 15/15 даст 1, а потом, после несложных расчетов, получим, что 15 пренадлежит интервалу 16-29. Соответственно ответ будет не 15, а 30

Comment: Спасибо! Поняла ошибку свою. А что использовать лучше : расчета с Math или  выборку из массива (var range = [15,30,45,0]; number = range[parseInt(Math.floor/15)];)???

Comment: @ennet, не совсем понял вопрос. А вот эта запись скорее всего с опечаткой: Math.floor/15

Comment: да простите, точно! http://jsfiddle.net/h20rbhLy/2/ я имела в виду, на сколько лучше если я просто буду выбирать данные интервала из массива?

Comment: Что вы хотите получить на выходе? Такое же решение? Если да, то моя формула лучше вашего решения с массивом, потому что оно вам даст неправильный ответ.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29265/discussion-between---and-ennet).

Answer (score 2):

Вот такая получилась функция: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/e65dx3tz/

```
var nums = [1, 7, 15, 23, 31, 40, 51, 59];

function roundMe (num) {
    var coef = 15;
    var res = Math.ceil(num / coef);
    return res * coef;
}

nums.forEach(function (item) {
    var result = roundMe(item);
    console.log(item, result);
    // 1 -> 15
    // 7 -> 15
    // 15 -> 15
    // 23 -> 30
    // 31 -> 45
    // 40 -> 45
    // 51 -> 60
    // 59 -> 60
});
```

UPD: немного поправил

Comment: alert(roundMe(15)); --> выдает 30, а должен 15

Comment: да, сделано немного наспех.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не сделать проще. У нас известен интервал. В Вашем случае это 15, назовем его `period`. Теперь берем любое число, например, 36.

1. `Math.round(36 / period)`
2. Прибавляем к полученному результату единицу и умножаем все на `period`

Пример.

1. Число 3. `Math.round(3 / period) == 0` => `(0 + 1) * period == 15`
2. Число 46. `Math.round(3 / period) == 3` => `(3 + 1) * period == 60`

P.S. Не заметил сразу, что на последнем интервале надо округлять до нуля. Тогда надо результат делить по остатку (`%`) на 60...

Comment: Должно быть не 60, а 0, когда от 46 до 59

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко, да, Вы правы, не заметил сразу.

Answer (score 1):

```
function a(e) {
    if (e % 15 != 0) {
        return ((Math.floor(e / 15) + 1) * 15) % 60
    }
    else
        return e
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот, по идее, Ваш же пример, только доработанный на основе собственных домыслов =)

```
var number = parseInt($('#number').text()),
result = $('#result');
console.log(number);
if(number <= 0 || number > 60) {        
    result.append('Неверное число');
    return;
}    
number = ((Math.floor((number - 1) / 15) + 1) * 15) % 60;    
result.append(number);
```

Comment: А теперь подставьте 15 и получите 30, а не 15

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко да, я знаю об этом. Но в задаче нет уточнения по этому поводу, поэтому я и написал, что требуется уточнение. А это один из примеров.

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко, хотя да, что-то прочел часть условия, и понял, что автор имел ввиду, что 15, 30, 45 не надо округлять (хотя логичнее было бы все же полные диапозоны писать, вроде 1-15, 16-30 и т.д.) =) Сейчас внесу корректировку тогда