# Как округлить число до десятых?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Из примера получается
3081 и 771

Как округлить до?
3080 и 770

А ещё лучше до?
3050 и 750

```js
$(".subtotal1").text (Math.ceil(2800 * 1.1));
$(".subtotal2").text (Math.ceil(700 * 1.1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="subtotal1"></span>
<span class="subtotal2"></span>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Округлить число к заданному интервалу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451823/%d0%9e%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83)

Comment: Как вариант: `+(Math.round(3081 / 10)+'0')`(Замените метод у `Math` в зависимости о задачи)

Comment: Т.е. пробовать `Math.floor()` или `Math.trunc()` вы даже не стали?

Comment: @EzioMercer, я думаю имелось ввиду округление не дробной части, а целого числа. Как в ссылке из комментария Эникейщик.

Comment: @OliverPatterson в ссылке ответ на вопрос на "А ещё лучше", я же дал комментарий к "Как округлить". Просто дело в том, что после умножения на `1.1` алгоритм умножения уходит в запой и выдёт нужный ответ с оооооочень маленькой дробной частью, и потому при округлении вверх, у него получается на 1 больше чем надо

Answer (score 1):

```js
function rounding(number, coarseness){
    return Math.floor(number / coarseness) * coarseness;
}
console.log(rounding(3081, 10) + " и " + rounding(771, 10));
console.log(`${rounding(3081, 50)} и ${rounding(771, 50)}`);
```